# Data is not displaying in table properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

i am using laravel and sending data through json and iterate that data using jquery in a table the data is displaying in table but along with it showing "No data available in table" i am sharing image and code below.

[image]

Html COde

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" >
                <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped custom-table datatable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Purchase From</th>
                    <th>Purchase Date</th>
                    <th>Purchased For</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Paid By</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody id="t_data">

             </tbody>
             </table>
             </div>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Jquery Code

```
 $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                       url:'/expense-report',
                        type:'post',
                        data:datastring,

                        success:function(data){

                            //console.log(data);
                            $.each(data, function() {
                            $.each(this, function(index, value) {
                                $("#t_data").append('<tr><td>'+value.item_name+'</td><td>'+value.purchase_from+'</td><td>'+value.purchase_date+'</td><td>'+value.purchase_for+'</td><td>'+value.amount+'</td><td>'+value.paid_by+'</td></tr>');
                             });
                            });

                               $(".mny").html('Total Money Spent : '+data.sum);



                            },
                        error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                         }


                    });
```

Comment: When did you call the function to initialize the datatable? Could you try calling it after you appended the rows?

Comment: If you are using Datatbale then after update table  you have to update Datatbale.

Comment: @NasirKamal      `$('.datatable').DataTable().destroy();
                                $.each(data, function() {
                                $.each(this, function(index, value) {
                                    $("#t_data").append('<tr><td>'+value.item_name+'</td><td>'+value.purchase_from+'</td><td>'+value.purchase_date+'</td><td>'+value.purchase_for+'</td><td>'+value.amount+'</td><td>'+value.paid_by+'</td></tr>');
                                    
                     });
                       });
                                    $('.datatable').DataTable().draw();`

Comment: @NasirKamal  i'm doing this in success destroying the table first then iterate the tr  then after the loop draw it ...its working perfectly but when i hit again for a new data the data is appending with previous data or we can say new data is showing with previous data......

Comment: @JudeMaranga    on success or i'm not initialize it i'm just adding the tr in the above html code

Comment: Please update your post with latest approach you tried, either you wanna use $.ajax or using Datatables ajax option to load data

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example of datatable.
You only need to change JSON.

```js
var dataSet = [{"id":2,"item_name":"vgbhjnkim","purchase_from":"vgbhnjkml","purchase_date":"24\/07\/2019","purchase_for":"Tea","amount":"50","paid_by":"Cash","created_at":"2019-07-24 14:16:06","updated_at":"2019-07-24 14:16:06"}]
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { data: "item_name" },
            { data: "purchase_from" },
            { data: "purchase_date" },
            { data: "amount" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                    <table id="example" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="datatable table  table-bordered ">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>From</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                   </table>
```

**Edit :** 
First check if dataTable exist or not, if it does then destroy dataTable and recreate it

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#example")) {
  $('#example').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}

$("#example").dataTable({...

                });
```

Comment: i tried this code but not displaying the data , yes data is coming and i am seeing it in response or preview but not displaying in the table

Comment: @Devvivek Please share your JSON.

Comment: $data=expense::select('*')->where('purchase_for',$d)->get();
         $sum=expense::select('*')->where('purchase_for',$d)->sum('amount');

         return response()->json(['sum'=>$sum,'data'=>$data]);

Comment: @Devvivek I am taking about this type of JSON.
[{"Name":"Harris Teeter","Title":"Manager","Office":"Home","Salary":"0.000000"}]

Comment: $('#example').DataTable( {
                                        data: data,
                                        columns: [
                                         { data: "item_name" },
                                         { data: "purchase_from" },
                                         { data: "purchase_date" },
                                         { data: "purchase_for" },
                                         { data: "amount" },
                                         { data: "paid_by" }
                           ]
                           });

Comment: i changed the table id to example

Comment: sorry to not understand again u mean the data comes in response right?

Comment: @Devvivek Yes that JSON data

Comment: "data":[{"id":2,"item_name":"vgbhjnkim","purchase_from":"vgbhnjkml","purchase_date":"24\/07\/2019","purchase_for":"Tea","amount":"50","paid_by":"Cash","created_at":"2019-07-24 14:16:06","updated_at":"2019-07-24 14:16:06"},{"id":3,

Comment: @Devvivek I have updated the above code please check

Comment: not working bro showing the popup to reinitialize the table...and if i add destroy:true then it not showing any popup but not displaying any data in table but in response showing all data....

Comment: @Devvivek Also Which version of datatable you used?

Comment: errror msg:  DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: sorry to say bro but i have tried in all the manner before the success, in the success, in document ready but still showing no data available ....and data is coming in json response.

Comment: are you available??